# php and search function error

Tags: php, html, mysql, dreamweaver

i am creating a search function or process to select from the database and display data in a listdropbox for the selection of countries that are already exist in the MySQL database   but i got an error and i do not know how to fix it can anyone help me i am new to php. the error is ( **Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Unnamed Site 2\resources\searchForm.php on line 36**)

## search.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search page</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
.searchtitle {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<!--<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>-->
<table width="80%" height="432">
  <tr>
    <td width="14%" valign="top"><!--<?php require_once('leftsideBar.php'); ?>-->
</td>
    <td width="86%" valign="top"><h2 class="searchtitle">Search Types</h2>
      <table width="95%" height="94">
      <form action="searchProcess.php" method="post" id="searchForm">

        <tr>
          <td width="20%"><label for="searchByName2">By Name</label>
            <select name="searchByName" id="searchByName2">
            </select></td>
          <td width="20%"><label for="searchByCountry">By Country</label>
            <select name="searchByCountry" id="searchByCountry">
             <option id="0">--select your country--</option>
             <?php
               require_once('Connections/connfor_lamelchameltest.php'); 

               $getallCountries = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country");
               while($viewallCountries = mysql_fetch_array($getallCountries)){

                ?>

               <option id="<?php echo $viewallCountries['country_id']; ?> "><?php echo $viewallCountries['country_name'] ?></option>
                 <?php } ?>

            </select></td>
          <td width="25%"><label for="searchByGovernorate">By Governorate</label>
            <select name="searchByGovernorate" id="searchByGovernorate">
            </select></td>
          <td width="15%"><label for="searchByCity">By City</label>
            <select name="searchByCity" id="searchByCity">
            </select></td>
          <td width="20%"><label for="searchBySpecialization">By Specialization</label>
            <select name="searchBySpecialization" id="searchBySpecialization">
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
      </table>

  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

## connfor_lamelchameltest.php

```
<?php
$hostname_conn = "localhost";
$database_conn = "lam_el_chamel_db";
$username_conn = "root";
$password_conn = ".....";
$conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

i add my connfig file

Comment: do you have data in the table?

Comment: thats because your query failed, and returned FALSE..!

Comment: Execute the query in phpmyadmin or any other mysql IDE to know whether it return any data

Comment: no guys the table is not empty it contain names and ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use `mysql_num_rows` here, it will check whether query returned any rows or not.

```
 $getallCountries = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country");
 if(mysql_num_rows($getallCountries) > 0) {
     while($viewallCountries = mysql_fetch_array($getallCountries)){
     // insert inside option
     }
 }
```

you haven't selected database use this code for selecting db

```
$conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
```

change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: i tried your solution now i got this error **Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Unnamed Site 2\resources\searchForm.php on line 36**

Comment: @devleb show your db connection file.

Comment: ok i show my connection file can you help me ??

Comment: @devleb see edited answer. Now it will solve your problem. :)

Comment: @devleb And accepting an answer is good habit, it it has solved your problem. :)

Comment: ohhh sorry for this mistake thank you  now the error disappear but it not display any data in the dropdownlist but the table contain data

Comment: @devleb see edited answer. change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: no the column's names are correct what the hell is the error now it make me crazy

Comment: i changed it nothing change i still do not get the data

Comment: you changed `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: yessss i did and still not getting any data

Answer (score 3):

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns `FALSE` if query fails. You need to check returned value. If it is `FALSE`, you can use [mysql_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to get error message from database.